# Ubuntu 20.04 crash after type in password

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Two days ago, I opened my computer and I found my ubuntu was crashed. I reinstall ubuntu several times and I notice that this crash always happens after I install the nvidia driver.

So basically, what happened to my computer is: after I type in my password, the whole system crashed, and the only thing I can see is a grainy screen, I had to force a shutdown. This situation will disappear after I uninstall my nvidia driver.

I have tried a lot of different ways to install my nvidia driver, but I always got the same problem. I also try to add 'nomodeset' on the grub file, still didn't work.

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and my GPU is RTX2060, my CPU is AMD Ryzen 7 4800H.

It is a nightmare to me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Besides, the crash grainy screen also happens when I try to wake my computer.(no nvidia driver)

Comment: Can you go to terminal mode and check your Hard Disk? sudo fsck -y /dev/sdb

Comment: it shows fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sdb
Possibly non-existent device?

Comment: That type of hard Disk you have?